# Add double quotes in aws command in python

Tags: python, string, shell, double-quotes

Below is my required output.

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --region "us-west-2" --user-pool-id "us-west-2_TEST" --filter "email = \"test@test.com\"" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text
```

I am trying to achieve this syntax using **Python** but getting some syntax error. I am stuck.

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --region "+region+" --user-pool-id "+user_pool_id+" --filter \"email = \"+email+\"\" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text
```

Please note that similar syntax i am using in **Shell Script** and its working fine.

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --region "$region" --user-pool-id "$userpool_id" --filter "email = \"$email\"" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text
```

Anyone can help me?

This may be similar with other questions, But i need extra double quotes inside command.

> UPDATE:

I am able to get something like **"email = "test@test.com""** using below command.

```
"aws cognito-idp list-users --region "+region+" --user-pool-id "+user_pool_id+" --filter \"email = \""+email+"\"\" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text"
```

**But I need an extra backslash before double quotes of email id.**

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing quotation marks at the beginning/end of your Python string and around the email escape (i.e. it should be `"aws cognito-idp list-users --region " + region + " --user-pool-id " + user_pool_id + " --filter \"email= \"" + email + "\" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text"`) but the bigger issue is - why do you want it as a string? If you need to call the command in AWS CLI (and don't want to use `boto` directly) use  `subprocess.check_output()`, pass your arguments as a list and let Python do the necessary escaping.

Comment: There is a Python library [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which includes [Cognito support](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html).  That might be a better place to start than running shell commands.

Comment: @David I am using boto3 for reading some data from s3 bucket. But how can i use boto3 to run this ``aws cli`` commands?

Comment: That would be worth a separate question, but you chould start here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
"aws cognito-idp list-users --region "+region+" --user-pool-id "+user_pool_id+" --filter \"email = \\\""+email+"\\\"\" --query 'Users[0].Username' --output text"
```

**\\"** will add backslash along with double quotes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
cmd = 'aws cognito-idp list-users --region "{0}" --user-pool-id "{1}" --filter \"email = \"{2}\" --query "{3}" --output text'.format("us-west-2", "us-west-2_TEST", "test@test.com",  Users[0].Username)
print(cmd)
```

Comment: it's nice. Maybe I will use this in future!